Explain what happens in the alpha rich freeze out phase of a core collapse supernova(ccSNe) and which reactions takes place
In a core collapse supernova many nuclear reactions takes place and one of them is phase known as alpha rich freeze out phase, it is said to be very important in the production of alpha rich heavy nuclei in the ISM. and plays main role in the nucleosynthesis of heavy nuclei.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
